# JAVA - Performance with string concatenation in logging while logging is off

Tags: java, string, performance, logging, string-concatenation

for a project my project group and I have created a program with a somewhat complicated algorithm. In this algorithm we use a lot of `logger.finest`, `logger.finer` etc. When running the default IntelliJ Profiler (for windows) 'Java Flight Recorder' we get the following result (Percentage is amount of total time of execution spend in said functions):

[image]

There is a lot of string concatination going on for logging which isn't even saved to a file because the logging is off:

```
Level.OFF
```

The string concatination doesn't stop as it's just a parameter of the functions.

We've thought of multiple solutions which all have their flaws:

1. **Using an external (Helper) Method/Class that has an `if` statement for logging. Something like**:

```
// Psuedo Code
public static void log(String msg_id) {
    if (should log) {
        log(msg);
    }
}
```

While this specific wouldn't work either way, maybe working with ID's or `Callable`s could. The main drawback for this is that the logging references for classes and methods are lost. Every line will say the logging came from Helper.log

2. **Another thing we thought we could try is put if statements before every log line**:

```
if(should log) {
    log("msg");
}
```

This, of course would work but would clutter all files and would be a pain to maintain, constantly asking someone to write `if`s for very logging line.

3. **We could write a script which removes all log lines for when we want to run the program at full speed**:

But this feels hands down ridiculous...

---

### TLDR;

I want to find a clean and somewhat proper way to stop the string concatination when logging is off as it's a massive performance decrease. 
I've tried a seperate helper class, many `if`s and external scripts but they don't feel like a proper solutions...

Comment: "*There is a lot of string concatination going on for logging*" **Why?** You shouldn't be using any concatenation directly. You should use [parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)

Comment: @Michael Wow. I've put some time in this question and the first comment is a perfect answer. Thanks. I wasn't able to find the question you marked as 'already answered here'.

Comment: Don't worry. It's good to have signposts. I was able to work backwards because I knew the term "parameterized logging" - it's probably much harder to find that if you don't.

Comment: Hey @Michael, not sure if you'd read this but I'm still having problems with `.toString()` methods. They still run before the parameterization. I feel like an if statement in every `toString()` wouldn't be very nice but I don't see another option. Should I open a new thread?

Comment: As in you're doing this `log.info("My log {}", someObject.toString())` ?

Comment: If so, you don't need to call `toString` explicitly. Just do `log.info("My log {}", someObject)`

Comment: No not really, it's a function which makes a list of objects and calls all objects `toString()` method. like: `private String getListAsString()`

Comment: I think I maybe get what you're saying but I'm not certain and don't want to guess. Make another question and feel free to post the link here

Comment: Thanks, I've asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284520/java-string-parameterization-performace-loss-on-indirect-tostring-methods