# Java String Parameterization - Performace loss on indirect toString methods

Tags: java, performance, string-concatenation

I've got a `method` like this:

```
private String getOrderListAsString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append("Sell list:");
    for (Order o : sellOrderList) {
        str.append("\nSale: ").append(o);
    }
    str.append("Buy list:");
    for (Order o : buyOrderList) {
        str.append("\nBuy:  ").append(o);
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

It's called with logging parameterization like so:
*We're using [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) as a logger.*

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", getOrderListAsString());
```

The problem is that the string concatination is still being done even if the logger level is `Level.OFF`.
To get around this we've added an `if` statement at the start of the method:

```
// Declaration:
boolean shouldLog = DebugWriter.getInstance().getLogger().getLevel() != Level.OFF;
// Usage in function:
if(!shouldLog) return null;
```

But it feels like this could be done in a more clever way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the entire project is within my control. In theory I could change anything

Comment: The way you have written the code, method `getOrderListAsString()` will ___always___ be called, regardless of the log level. You need to check the log level before generating the log message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8+, then *java.util.Logger* has an overload of the `log` method that takes a Supplier

```
public void log(Level level,
            Supplier<String> msgSupplier)
```

Now, you can make the string generated from a supplier like

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, () -> getOrderListAsString());
```

or, using method reference

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, this::getOrderListAsString);
```

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Comment: Only downside to this would be that I can't use the `"{0}"` notation with it

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#info-java.util.function.Supplier-) has overloads that take `Supplier<String>` but not in combination with a format string. So you can use it like this:

```
logger.info(() -> getOrderListAsString());
```

Or create a new abstraction `OrderList` that has a `toString()` method. Then you can simply pass it as a parameter, and the logger will invoke `toString()`, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Same spirit as Eran's answer, but just wrap the argument rather than change the log implementation

```
public class LazyToString
{
    private final Supplier<String> stringSupplier;

    public LazyToString(Supplier<String> stringSupplier)
    {
        this.stringSupplier = stringSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return stringSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
log.info("Something happened {}", new LazyToString(this::getOrderListAsString));
```

If that's too verbose, you can create a static method call which creates the object rather than using new, maybe would look something like this

```
log.info("Something happened {}", lazy(this::getOrderListAsString));
```

Comment: Looks very nice. I'll definitely save it! For now I'll use the answer by @user7 as it's smaller and I don't need the `{}` parsing. But when I do I'll probably have to switch to this. Thanks for answering all the questions, also on the question before!